# Vulkan: (MSAA) Resolve only some color attachments of a subpass

Tags: vulkan

I think I'm setting things up correctly, but I'm still getting validation errors.

I'm trying to define a subpass with 2 color attachments: the first is the swapchain surface, and the second is a regular color attachment.
I want to perform multi-sampling on the second color attachment, but not the first.

Since there are 2 color attachments, I add 2 `pResolveAttachments` to the `VkSubpassDescription`. The first `VkAttachmentReference` entry, which refers to the swapchain surface, is defined with
`.attachment` as `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`. That is:

```
pResolveAttachments[0].attachment=VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED
```

From my understanding, this should prevent the Vulkan from doing a resolve operation on `pColorAttachments[0]`.

Per Spec:

> if pResolveAttachments is not NULL, each of its elements corresponds
> to a color attachment  (the element in pColorAttachments at the same
> index), and a multisample resolve operation is defined for each
> attachment.  At the end of each subpass, multisample resolve
> operations read the subpass’s color attachments, and resolve the
> samples  for each pixel within the render area to the same pixel
> location in the corresponding resolve attachments,  unless the resolve
> attachment index is VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED.

However, I get the validation errors. What am I doing wrong?

Validation Errors:
[image: Validation Errors]

Nvidia Nsight:
[image]

From my log file:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of errors and code. Post the actual text. Also, the validation errors are telling you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: Color attachment 0 has sample count of 1 bit, but the corresponding pResolveAttachments is VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED.

Comment: And what of the other error?

Comment: Yes, that error is present, as well. But, I'm trying to handle one error at a time, and so I only asked about the first error.

Comment: I understand that I'm probably doing something incorrect. My position is that, from my perspective, I seem to be following the spec correctly, but I'm still getting the validation error, so obviously I'm not seeing where my own error is.

Answer (score 1):

A Vulkan limitation that subsumes this error is that all output attachments need to have the same sample count. So, regardless of the MSAA operation, this particular usecase is not valid because the first color attachment is the swapchain surface, and the second is a color attachment. Swapchain images can only have sample count of 1.

The overarching error is about color attachments not having the same sample count. [1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSubpassDescription-pColorAttachments-01417)